# wix: display contact info in ARP as a hyperlink

Tags: wix, nsis

My application needs to display the contact details in ARP entries as a hyperlink... Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Why did you tag this question with both NSIS and WIX? Are you just looking for a general answer?

Comment: I will be using both together.. Need the answer in wix....

Answer (score 1):

Set URLInfoAbout or one of the other strings listed [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs#Optional_values) or [here](http://windowssucks.wordpress.com/win-registry-uninstall-values/) (MSDN lists some of them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but the list is incomplete and brings MSI specific things into the mix)

Answer (score 1):

Set the wix property ARPURLINFOABOUT:

```
<Property Id="ARPURLINFOABOUT" Value="www.company.com/product" />
```

Here are some other [WiX ARP properties](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/09/from-msi-to-wix-part-2.aspx) that you can use to configure what is displayed in Add/Remove programs.

Comment: Is it that i should place this property with the registry entries... I mean the file which has all the declarations of registries?

Comment: It can go anywhere under your <product> element. This can be your main .wxs file but doesn't have to. If you have a .wxs file that has a bunch of registry elements, it can probably go there as well. The WiX help lists what elements are parents of the property element: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_property.htm